# Basic JS + WebDev help

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a little Problem. I have seven `<select>`'s. The go from left to right counting up.

```
<select id="sel_1" onchange="evalonsubmit('sel_1',1);">
<select id="sel_2" onchange="evalonsubmit('sel_2',2);">
```

That goes from 1 to 7 in this way.

The logic is easy. On click check if the value is -1 if it is disable everything on the right and set it to -1. if it is not -1 then enable the  the right of the clicked one (+1 so to say)

And that's the code:

```
function evalonsubmit(ID, n)
{
    var ElementID = document.getElementById(ID);
    if(ElementID.value = -1) {
        for (var i = n + 1; i <= 7; i++){
            var newID = "sel_" + i;
            var newValue = document.getElementById();
            newValue.disable = true;
            newValue.value = -1
        }
    } else {
        var newID = "sel_"+(n+1)
        var newValue = document.getElementById();
        newValue.disable = false;
    }
}
```

Can somebody kind JS hacker help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fixed some simple mistakes in your code ..

```
function evalonsubmit(ID, n)
{
    var ElementID = document.getElementById(ID);
    if (ElementID.value == -1){
        for (var i=n+1; i <= 7; i++){
            var newID = "sel_" + i;
            var newValue = document.getElementById(newID);
            newValue.disable = true;
            newValue.value = -1
        }
    } else {
        var newID = "sel_"+(n+1)
        var newValue = document.getElementById(newID);
        newValue.disable = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you want, but it probably should be:

```
if (ElementID.value == -1){
//                   ^---  two = , otherwise you assign the value
```

and

```
var newID = "sel_" + i;
var newValue = document.getElementById(newID);
//                     pass parameter ---^
```

Same in the `else` branch.

---

Besides that, I would give your variables more meaningful names. E.g. `ElementID` lets you assume that the value is an ID. But it is not. It is a DOM element. Same for `newValue`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the parameter in a couple of your calls to `document.getElementById`, and the property for disabling a `<select>` is `disabled`, not `disable`. You also have `=` where you need `==`.

```
function evalonsubmit(ID, n)
{
    var ElementID = document.getElementById(ID);
    if (ElementID.value == -1){
        for (var i=n+1; i <= 7; i++){
            var newID = "sel_" + i;
            var newValue = document.getElementById(newID);
            newValue.disabled = true;
            newValue.value = -1;
        }
    } else {
        var newID = "sel_"+(n+1);
        var newValue = document.getElementById(newID);
        newValue.disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

### HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <select onchange="evalonsubmit(this);" />

    <select onchange="evalonsubmit(this);" />
    <select onchange="evalonsubmit(this);" />
</div>
```

### JS:

```
function nextElement(current)
{
    do
        current = current.nextSibling;
    while (current && current.nodeType != 1);

    return current;
}

function evalonsubmit(elem)
{
    if(elem.value == -1)
        while(elem = nextElement(elem)) {
            elem.disabled = true;
            elem.value = -1
        }
    else if(elem = nextElement(elem))
        elem.disabled = false;
}
```

That removes the need for `id`s on the `<select>` elements, as following elements can be grabbed with `.nextSibling`. The `nextElement()` function is to avoid grabbing text nodes.